# Which confederacy is Ps83 relating to?

Tags: prophecy

**PSALM 83:5** *For they have consulted together with one consent; They form a confederacy against You:*

Is there any scriptural evidence to support which confederacy this relates to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is clear evidence. The ‘confederation’ formed against Israel is reflected throughout scripture. As well as history. Nations that are ‘motivated’ by spiritual entities.

We see these represented in Daniel, Isaiah, Joel, Jeremiah, Zechariah, etc, including the Psalm you quoted. There is debate as to whether this has been fulfilled, or is yet to be fulfilled, or both. (Hebraic prophecy is *pattern*, so multiple fulfilment is arguable.). But you didn’t ask this, you simply wanted the makeup of the confederation.

This is best ‘seen’ in Daniel. The nations are [mostly] those surrounding Israel. However those in Psalm 83 are more specific. And for ‘scriptural evidence’ we don’t even need to leave this Psalm.

**PSALM 83:6** *The tents of Edom and the Ishmaelites; Moab and the Hagrites;* **7** *Gebal, Ammon, and Amalek; Philistia with the inhabitants of Tyre;* **8** *Assyria also has joined with them; They have helped the children of Lot. Selah*

There is some (minor) disagreements over exactly which modern nations these are. Philistia *is* the current area of Gaza, and Lebanon is also represented, as is Syria and south of Jordan (Edom). But one ‘key’ to help identify those *possibly* involved is found in verse 4.

**PSALM 83:4** *They have said, “Come, and let us cut them off from being a nation, That the name of Israel may be remembered no more.”*

The intent to wipe Israel of the map is spiritual. So according to verse 4, it is *this* anti Semitism that forms the ‘foundation’ for this confederation.

Comment: @0000 If there was clear *scriptural* evidence there wouldn’t (shouldn’t) be (too) much debate. My personal perspective is that this is *yet* to happen. One (of a few reasons) is that Philistia (Gaza) has never been invaded - Joshua left that area out (and that area has been a thorn ever since). But it *will* happen -soon, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> Psalms 83:5 "For they have consulted together with one consent: They
> hare confederate against Thee:

The religious leaders of today formed their own traditions, and pattern of thought, and they stick together like glue. Sure they have their own denominational boundaries, but together challenge anyone that goes against their dogma in force. So who are we talking about? The Kenites of course, for they control most of the thought of the seminaries, and denominations. The Kenites have put together a confederacy against God's nations, to over-ride and they are a threat even to our great nation.

However in the end, we will have the victory in Christ. It is time for the Christians in our nation, and around the world to wake up. Now we will have ten nations or peoples named, and God will ask us to stop a moment and consider what has been said, with a "Selah".

Then God will give us a seven fold destruction called down on their heads. We are talking about prophecy here. There are seven types of destruction used to give Israel victories that came from God. However to these ten nations, this has not been accomplished to this date. However it shall come to pass very shortly, in these end times. That is why it is important to pay attention to what is said here.

In the back of your Companion Bible, Appendix ten, we can read what numbers mean, in "The spiritual significance of numbers."

Ten: Denotes "Ordininal perfection; meaning a new beginning or first, meaning the prior is over and done with."

Seven: Denotes "Spiritual perfection; This is the hall-mark of the Holy Spirit's work. He is the author of God's Word, it is the water-mark on the paper of where it was manufactured.

Combine the ten and the seven and you have seventeen and that denotes victory. It is the sons of God, God's elect that will have the victory when this earth age is completed. Those that Love our Heavenly Father, and understand and obey His Word, will have the victory. So these are the ten that stand against almighty God, that hold their heads up high, and say there is not God.

> Psalms 83:6 "The tabernacles of Edom, and the Ishmaelites; Of Moab,
> and the Hagarenes;"

"Edom" in the Hebrew tongue, means "red". It is the children of Esau, and today they are the Russians. This is not talking about the individuals, but the system of that nation. We have many good Christians in that nation today, and they have paid a price for their beliefs. There she stand in her fallen state, with her people crying to return to their Godless form of Communism.

The "Ishmaelites, of Moab": that means of His own people. These are the tribes of the sons of Ishmael, the first son of Abraham but through the bond servant, Hagar. We read in Genesis 17 that the covenant between God and Abraham was with Sarah also, and the only son Isaac came from Sarah was in her old age. The one to carry the covenant would be Isaac, and he would pass it on to Jacob, who's name was changed to Israel. We read in Genesis 48 how the Covenant promises, that of land, a seed, and blessing was passed on from Jacob to Joseph's two sons Ephraim and Manasseh. So here we see some of our own people, of the seed of Abraham that will turn against Christianity.

The " Hagarenes ", were also tied to Abraham, through that bond servant Hagar. The word Hagar in the Hebrew means "flight". Stop and look at the middle east and see the people in flight, and these people are all from the offspring of Hagar through Ishmael.

---

Source:
https://www.theseason.org/psalms/psalms83.htm

For a better grasp of the term kenite, i did write up a short reply here
[What made Cain ‘of the wicked one’?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/69360/what-made-cain-of-the-wicked-one/69367#69367)

Comment: I am awarding you the bounty, not because of your answer but because you have the least amount of reputation. It's to help you can gain more functionality. Reputation here doesn't mean that some one has knowledge rather it means they have participated a lot.

Comment: okay thanks . i got nothing else to do lately. waiting on some bicycle parts. might as well share some of what I have learned.

Answer (score 0):

Psalms 83 may refer to the event described in 2 Chronicles 20, at time Jehoshaphat was king of Judah.

Psalms 83 was titled "A song. A psalm of Asaph". 2 Chronicles 20:14 read

> 14 Then the Spirit of the Lord came on Jahaziel son of Zechariah, the son of Benaiah, the son of Jeiel, the son of Mattaniah, **a Levite and descendant of Asaph**, as he stood in the assembly. (NIV)

Psalm 83 mentioned an alliance of;

- 83:6 - the tents of Edom and the Ishmaelites, of Moab and the Hagrites,
- 83:7 - Byblos, Ammon and Amalek, Philistia, with the people of Tyre.
- 83:8 - Even Assyria has joined them to reinforce Lot’s descendants

2 Chronicles 20 mentioned an alliance of Ammon, Moab and Edom (Mount Seir) as read from 2 Chronicles 20:22

> 22 As they began to sing and praise, the Lord set ambushes against the
> men of **Ammon and Moab and Mount Seir who were invading Judah**, and they
> were defeated. (NIV)

Now then, can we justify these two alliances were the same?

In the first list of 83:6, it mentioned Edom, Moab and the Ishmaelites, and Hagrites, likely the descendants of Hagar and should also be a tribe of Ishmaelites.

The third wife of Esau was an Ishmaelites, as we read Gen 28:9

> 9 so he (Esau) went to Ishmael and married Mahalath, the sister of Nebaioth and daughter of Ishmael son of Abraham, in addition to the wives he already had. (NIV)

According to encyclopedia.com, Ishmaelites were nomadic tribes live in the desert, south of Edom. They were likely mercenary to help Edom.

In the second list of 83:7, there were Byblos, Ammon and Amalek, Philistia and Tyre. Byblos, Philistia and Tyre were Phoenicians likely mercenary to help Ammon. Amalekites was descendant of Esau, who was first major tribe to resist the Israelites took over Canaan (Gen 17). They were staunch enemy of the Israelites, but were nearly extinct at time of Saul, when Agag, probably the last king of Amalek, was killed (1 Sam 15:33). Therefore the Amalek mentioned was likely not a nation, but the remnant of Amalekites.

In the third list only Assyria was mentioned. Jehoshaphat reigned at 870-849BC. The Neo-Assyrian Empire came to a prominent power state from Shalmaneser III (859-824BC). Again this Assyrian was likely mercenary.

Conclusion

To the best understanding meanwhile, Psalm 83 was related to the event described in 2 Chronicles 20.